# mootools touchevents not being bound when used with phonegap

Tags: javascript, android, cordova, mootools, cordova-2.0.0

I am building an android sample app using mootools and phonegap.

When i access my html/javascript using the android browser, it works fine. but when i create an app with phonegap, it stops listening to the events.

```
el.addEvent('mousedown', touchednow.bind(this));
el.addEvent('touchstart', touchednow.bind(this));
```

These lines work in browser but not once packed in phonegap.
nothing happens when i touch to the button. I have simple alert in the function touchednow
I'm using MooTools version 1.2.4 and phonegap(cordova) 2.0

Does phonegap prevents mootools from listening to events ?

please note other code like el.setstyles works fine with phonegap too. it's just the events that do not work.

Comment: mootools 1.2.4? thats old. and you need support for native events enabled. `Element.NativeEvents.touchstart = 2`, though I am not sure if this was in the 1.2.x branch or if it came in 1.3.x. I suggest you look at mootools 1.4.5 and moobile.

Comment: you are right, thats old. but touch events are supported in 1.2.4, i guess it started from 1.2.4. and i tested this thing in android browser and it works fine. So I think it has something to do with phonegap it works in android browser though !
still, I will check 1.4.5 out

Comment: touch events are NOT supported in 1.2.4 in the way you think they are. see on github: https://github.com/mootools/mootools-core/blob/1.2.4/Source/Element/Element.Event.js#L121-129 - you still want to tell mootools how to treat the event and how to attach it/bubble it. btw. since you use phonegap, build a custom ver of mootools w/o all the ie stuff, see the blog.

Comment: @DimitarChristoff you are right, it is not supported with 1.2.4. It worked previously because it simulated mouse clicks as touch events.
changed it to 1.4.5 and working fine on device :) Thanks a lot!